# Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform equation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform

How can I obtain de inverse discrete Fourier Transform of the following equation:

\begin{equation}
X(j\omega)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k\delta(\omega-\frac{k\pi}{2})
\end{equation}

I have tried by expanding its Fourier series and then doing the inverse and by tables, but I end up obtaining different results, and I am unsure which is the correct one.
A step-by-step solution would be very helpful.

Solution 1 (by Fourier Series)
The signal could be written by its Fourier series in this way
\begin{equation}
X(j\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (1-e^{-jk\pi})e^{jk2\omega}
\end{equation}
Doing the inverse by definition
\begin{equation}
x(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} X(j\omega)e^{j\omega n}d\omega
\end{equation}
Obtaining
\begin{equation}
x(n)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta(n+2k)-e^{-jk\pi}\delta(n+2k))
\end{equation}

Solution 2 (by table)
\begin{equation}
x(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^k e^{jkn\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k}\delta(\omega-\frac{\pi}{2})}= \delta(\omega-\frac{\pi}{2}) \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k}}$ . I think there is a mistake

Comment: It's an impulse train, sorry I forgot the k in the delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t we just take the inverse Fourier Transform directly:

$$
\begin{align}
x(n)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{X\left(j\omega\right)\cdot e^{jwn}\phantom{x}d\omega}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k}\cdot\delta\left(\omega-\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}\cdot e^{jwn}\phantom{x}d\omega}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k}\cdot e^{jkn\frac{\pi}{2}}}
\end{align}
$$

This aligns with the table so now we know your first method is incorrect or can be further simplified.